# How to clear clipboard on mac excel vba

Tags: macos, vba, excel, clipboard

`Application.CutCopyMode=False` on windows excel clears the dotted line and clipboard data is lost which is desirable.

But the same is not true for Mac OS. On Mac it clears the dotted line but the clipboard data is not lost.

Is there a single line or any method which will clear the clipboard on mac and windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code [here](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/macoffice/excel/clearclipboard.html), I dont have or use Mac so I cannot test this out but from reading the code it will assign "" (nothing in other words) to this clipboard.

Hope this works or at least gets you on the right direction

```
Public Function ClearMacClipBoard() As Boolean
    Dim myDO As DataObject

    On Error GoTo EndCMCB
    Set myDO = New DataObject
    myDO.SetText ""
    myDO.PutInClipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ClearMacClipBoard = True
EndCMCB:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**Edit:**

Slight change from comments to try and work both on Windows and Mac

This should skip any line of code that would noramlly bug out so when you try to run Mac code on Windows it will just skip it and vise-versa

```
Public Function ClearMacClipBoard() As Boolean
    Dim myDO As DataObject

    On Error GoTo Resume Next
    Set myDO = New DataObject
    myDO.SetText ""
    myDO.PutInClipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ClearMacClipBoard = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: But this wouldn't work on windows right ? I need something which is compatible on both systems

Comment: Are you after a single line that works for both Mac and Windows versions of Excel? Because the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` will clear it for Windows and `myDO.SetText ""` `myDO.PutInClipboard ` will clear for Mac, just change the `On error Goto EndCMCB` to `On error resume next`

Comment: No I am after anything that will work on both systems. Currently your example wont work on windows. Example: Let's say I have to run the same macro on different systems then it shouldn't give me any error.

Comment: I very much doubt there will be a single line of code to clear for both Mac and Windows and without a Mac PC I cannot even test for small variations

Comment: Ill change the code slightly and you can try using that see if it works

Comment: Use conditional compilation to apply separate Windows and Mac solutions.#If Mac Then<newline>'Mac Solution<newline>#Else<newline>'Windows Solution<newline>#End If